# Getting names of all children in has_many, :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I've got this bit of code which returns an array of IDs like `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
<% @articles.each do |a| %>
  <%= a.brand_ids %>
<% end %>
```

`Article` and `Brand` have a `has_many, :through` relationship. How would I return a list of the names of each brand instead of IDs? `a.brands.name` returns `Brand`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pluck`:

```
article = Article.find(17)
article.brands.pluck(:name)
```

Comment: brand model has `translates :name` attribute, hence I can't do `brands.pluck(:name)`, although `brands.first.name` works. How do I pluck the names of all the brands from the translation table?